# Could not load file or assembly System.Core 2.0.5.0 when reflecting over System.ValueTuple type TupleExtensions

Tags: c#, reflection

Depending on how an assembly is loaded the following code may throw the exception 'Could not load file or assembly System.Core 2.0.5.0'

```
foreach (var type in valueTupleAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(string), false);
}
```

Load or LoadFile results in the exception

```
var valueTupleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
var valueTupleAssembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
```

LoadFrom works fine

```
var valueTupleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

I understand that System.ValueTuple is retargetable and it's dependency on System.Core should resolve to whatever is executing.

I don't understand (1) why reflecting over TupleExtensions triggers assembly resolve for System.Core 2.0.5 (other types in same assembly do not) and (2) why LoadFrom doesn't have the same problem.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom/  states "LoadFrom() goes through Fusion and can be redirected to another assembly at a different path but with that same identity if one is already loaded in the LoadFrom context." So my guess for (2) is that Fusion redirects system.core 2.0.5 to the version that is available?